# "Political Events" in the Preface to the Second Edition of Spivak's Comprehensive Introduction Volume 2

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, biographical-details, social-context, mathematics-social-history

In the Preface to the second edition to Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*, Vol. 2, on p.vii says:

> The material in this Volume covers about what I would have completed in my class this term, had political events not intervened.

What political events is he referring to? The preface is signed at Brandeis University, July 6, 1970. The comment is not included in the third edition's preface.

I would prefer a factual account, although speculation is also welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a speculative answer: The Preface to the First Edition to Volume 1 included in the third edition (also of Volume 1) is signed at Brandeis University in March 1970; and in it there is no mention of political events. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970, my speculation is that Spivak is referring to the Vietnam War/ antiwar protests in the US.

Comment: I remember classes being interrupted at my uni in May 1970, in protest of the Kent State shootings.